# Darktable lens correction doesn't find lens automatically

Tags: darktable, lens-correction

I have been using darktable for sometime now on Debian.
But after I re-install the operating system, darktable does not find my lens automatically. Instead I have to choose the lens manually every time I want do lens correction on an image.
My lens is a Nikon DX VR AF-S NIKKOR 18-55mm 1:3.5-5.6G II

Any ideas why darktable behaves the differently?

**UPDATE:**

I found that back then I had installed via the backports of debian so after removing the current version. I install the darktable via the backports and now I have the 2.2.1 but the problem still exist.

running
`exiv2 -pt Pictures/101D5200/DSC_5641.NEF  | grep -ai lens`

gives

`Exif.Nikon3.LensType                         Byte        1  D G VR
Exif.Nikon3.Lens                             Rational    4  18-55mm F3.5-5.6
Exif.Nikon3.LensFStops                       Undefined   4  5.33333
Exif.NikonLd3.LensIDNumber                   Byte        1  162
Exif.NikonLd3.LensFStops                     Byte        1  F5.3`

in Darktable I'm selecting Nikon, Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G AF-S DX VR
isn't that correct?

**UPDATE2:**

I manually install the lensfun and run the update command. But darktable still does not select the lens automatically.

Comment: The answer from @Calyth below is generally correct, but it doesn't look like the name has been changed for this lens since it was added three years ago. Can you copy and paste here the exact name shown by darktable in the image information panel? Also, the exact name selected manually, if it differs?

Comment: It may also be failing to identify the camera, in dark table it needs to know the camera and lense.

Comment: @Calyth Maybe, but I assume not in this case, due to being able to manually select a lens.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle or anyone can give a link to an image that you know that darktable will find the lens automatically? I'm thinking that maybe this is a bug.

Comment: [This one](https://raw.pixls.us/getfile.php/1431/nice/Olympus%20-%20E-PL7%20-%2016bit%20(4:3).orf) should work.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle it didn't work so it must be a bug otherwise I cannot understand why it. [print screen](https://imgur.com/a/qEjtO)

Comment: Yes, it looks like something is weird with your installation. This might be more an issue for troubleshooting via Debian forums than a SE question. Unfortunately, different distros take different approaches to packaging lensfun, which complicates things.

Answer (score 2):

I've only seen failure to choose because the database is out of date.

Try updating the lensfun database, e.g. `sudo lensfun-update-data`. Do look at the documentation and stuff before you run some random ol' sudo command though ;)

Comment: You can also run the script as a user, and it will install the updates to ~/.local/share/lensfun instead of the system location.

Comment: Neither of these commands are available in my system. (debian jessie)

Comment: I installed manually the lensfun and run the update command. After that I checked if the lens connection in darktable selects the lens automatically. But the answer is negative.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Calyth -- Could it be that lensfun had been updated and re-installing Debian put you back a couple minor versions? You can get the lensfun-update-data command via:
  sudo apt-get install liblensfun-bin

Comment: The version of exiv2 is also relevant, although IIRC the latest release is not very recent.

Comment: Whoops, looks like there was finally an exiv2 update (to 0.26) in May, after almost two years... so that might be another thing to check.